# Upload PDF files to s3 from webpage running on chrome/android browser produces err: FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: android, google-chrome, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

Getting the weirdest bug. I have S3 PDF upload working perfectly from all other devices and browser using the AWS javascript sdk, except android devices.

When I click to upload a file I receive multiple aws PUT errors (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).

Again this ONLY happens from Android devices. The Google Pixel is the only Android device I've tested on. Upload works from all other desktop web browsers and iOS, including Chrome on iOS.

I don't think it's a browser issue, I think it is a filesystem issue. However, when I put console.logs all over the place. Every value I get back is correct. I'm able to log the file, the filename, the s3 bucket name, file type is application/pdf... everything checks out, but when the upload begins, I get hit with the err.

In my form, I'm using enctype of multipart/form-data if that helps.

[image: console errors from chrome on android (google pixel)]

[image: javascript code]

Comment: I have a very similar issue, and the same weird error message. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: The same thing works in Firefox for Android. This is getting even stranger...